# Combining scoped activerecord queries in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to build a facebook style feed of items for a user. The feed will contain recent notes (on books) made by a user or people the user follows combined with other notifications such as "user x that you follow started reading a new book". You get the idea.

So far I have a scope in my Note class which returns the notes I want:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :from_users_followed_by, lambda { |user| followed_by user }

  def self.followed_by(user)
    followed_ids = %(SELECT followed_id FROM relationships WHERE follower_id = :user_id)
    where("user_id IN (#{followed_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id", { :user_id => user })
  end
end
```

and a similar scope in my Readings class which returns records built when user starts reading a book:

```
class Reading < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :from_users_followed_by, lambda { |user| followed_by(user) }

  def self.followed_by(user)
    # is this not at risk of sql injection??
    followed_ids = %(SELECT followed_id FROM relationships WHERE follower_id = :user_id)
    # return readings where user_id IN (an array of user_ids that the user follows)
    where("reader_id IN (#{followed_ids}) OR reader_id = :user_id", { :user_id => user })
  end
end
```

Now this works fine and I can get arrays of objects from these no problem. I'm struggling to combine the two queries into a feed which is correctly ordered by creation time. The best I can do at the moment is my user class with a combined feed method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def combined_feed
    feed = Note.from_users_followed_by(self) | Reading.from_users_followed_by(self)

    feed.sort! do |a, b|
      a.created_at <=> b.created_at
    end
    feed.reverse
  end
end
```

Which gets me a combined feed but strikes me as being horrendously inefficient. How can I do the equivalent at the database level in rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would probably create an entirely separate model called FeedItem. Then, when certain events occur (such as the creation of a new note), you just create a new FeedItem record. Then you only have one table to query from and it will already be in the correct order.